# Having more than 2 options in Cognito Form

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm creating a form that has a drop-down box 'number of drivers' which has up to 4 options: (i.e. 1 driver, 2 drivers, 3 drivers & 4 drivers).

When I select 2 drivers, lots of fields pop up so each driver can enter their separate details. I've done this using the 'Show this when number of drivers is 2'. Now I want to do the same, but when I select 3 drivers I want all 3 lots of fields to pop up & when I select 4 all 4 fields to pop up.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to capture data for a variable list of items in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) is to use [Repeating Sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections).  This will allow you to create a form with a single Drivers repeating section that allows users to click Add Driver to add additional drivers.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use conditional visibility and a series of sections, you can make Section 2 visible when `=NumberOfDrivers >= 2`, Section 3 visible when `=NumberOfDrivers >= 3`, etc.  Pro-tip: once you create the first section for driver information, you can copy and paste the entire section for each additional driver.